# state is not getting updated in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, state-management, react-state-management

I am selecting a date using `react-native-community/datetimepicker`, and then on `onChange` function I am saving my selected date in a state

```
const [changedDate, setChangedDate] = useState<string | null>(null);

const onChange = (event: any, selectedDate: any) => {
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    var momentObj = moment(selectedDate, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
    var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setChangedDate(momentString); // <---- saving date in a state
};
```

then I am opening a modal:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        setSelectPickerModalVisible(!selectPickerModalVisible);
        console.log('date on modal>>>>', changedDate); // getting date in my console
    }}>
    <Text>open modal</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

console output:

```
date on modal>>>> 2021-11-27
```

You can see here, when I console my state then I am getting the selected date in console.

Then on `modal` I have a `onPress` function which has to do some work, below is this function:

onPress on `modal`

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={openImageUpload.bind(null, 'picker')}>
    <Text>upload</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

`openImageUpload` function

```
const openImageUpload = useCallback(
    (mode: 'picker' | 'camera' = 'picker') => {
        console.log('date on function: ', changedDate); //<--- here in console I am getting my state as null

        // some work
    },
    [uploadHandler],
);
```

console output:

```
date on function: null
```

I am not able to understand that why my state is getting `null` after it has been updated

Comment: Since you are using a Callback, it will only update with relevant data if uploadHandler changes. Try changing it in the regular function or change the dependencies so it reflects new changes

Comment: Might help might not but whenever  I use react-native I do `openImageUpload.bind(this, 'picker')` instead of `null`